# Object.create and delete property from newly created object

Tags: javascript

If Object.create makes new deep copy of the object, what should happen post deleting the property from the newly created object?

Expected Output: Undefined

Actual Output: Karna

Code

```js
var obj1 = {name:"Karna",loc:"Bengaluru"};

var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);

delete obj2.name;

console.log(obj2.name);
```

Could you please help me to understand why obj2.name still referring to obj1's property?

Comment: "Object.create makes new deep copy of the object" - it doesn't. Please re-read the functionality of `Object.create`.

Comment: You probably wanted `vat obj2 = {...obj1}`  or `Object.assign`

Comment: but console.log(obj1 === obj2); return 's false always.. @ASDFGerte

Comment: `obj1 === obj2` will be false there two different objects,. but obj2 now has these properties on the protototype, and not the actual object.  eg, although a silly thing to do -> `delete obj2.__proto__.name;` will delete it, but that's something you unlikely want to do.  It's maybe an idea reading up on what the prototype is -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes

Comment: I think you will like the upcoming [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) function.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.create` creates a new object with the argument object as prototype of the new object created (refer to the `__proto__` of the newly created object). It does not add the properties of `obj1` to `obj2`. So, if you invoke `delete` on `obj2`, it will delete the properties of obj2, and not the ones in the prototype.

Example:

```js
var obj1 = { name: 'John' }

var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);

console.log(obj2.__proto__ === obj1) // returns true

console.log(obj2.hasOwnProperty('name')) // returns false; 

console.log(obj2.name) // returns John 

delete obj2.name; // returns true

console.log(obj2.name) // returns John, since delete will not traverse the prototype chain to delete keys
```

More info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 0):

There two points you should pay atention:
1- Object.create doesn't make copy of original object, it creates a new object with the argument object as prototype of the new object created. (prototype property is not configurable property)
2- delete operator just works on `configurable` properties of an object.

so, prototype properties are not deletable by `delete` operator, because they're not  configurable.